# A combination of 1N4007 diodes in place of M7

Tags: diodes

Can I use a combination of 1N4007 diodes in place of M7? If yes, what's the arrangement? M7 is a surface mount general rectifier with a reverse voltage of 50  to 1000 and a forward current of 1 amp.

Comment: M7 doesn't look like any part number I'm familiar with. Also, it's 1N4007, with a 1 (one), not an I.

Comment: [M7](https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=13687) is the SMD equivalent of 1N4007 (VRRM = 1kV, IF = 1A) and is produced by a lot of Chinese manufacturers.

Comment: Would love to help you, but we don't have enough detail and context to give you a proper answer. Please add more information to your post.

Comment: thanks for the correction. kindly take a look http://www.kingtronics.com/diodes-rectifiers/m7-diode.html

Comment: Oh, it's an SMD marking. From the look of it, a diode marked M7 is just a 1N400x in surface-mount packaging. So a single 1N4007 would be theoretically identical (as long as you aren't using the diode in some breakdown mode), as the only thing that differs in the 1N400x series is reverse blocking voltage and the 1N4007 has the highest out of those.

Comment: Rohat Kilic, does that mean i can use just one 1N4007?

Comment: Thanks @RohatKılıç, I didn't initially recognise it as an SMD marking.

Comment: @BenjaminAmemor-Atito Since the M7 and the 1N4007 are electrically equivalent, you can use just one 1N4007 in place of an M7. Be careful the packaging though.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of it, a diode marked M7 is just a 1N400x in surface-mount packaging. So a single 1N4007 would be theoretically identical (as long as you aren't using the diode in some breakdown mode), as the only thing that differs in the 1N400x series is reverse blocking voltage and the 1N4007 has the highest out of those.